# Error Message : Unable to find element with xpath in phantomsJS

Tags: node.js, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using simple NodeJS script for testing google.com. phantomJS browser is used.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var assert = require('assert');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
withCapabilities({
    browserName : "phantomjs"
}).
usingServer('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub').build();

//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000);

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="gbqf"]')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    assert.equal("webdriver - Google Search", title);
 });

driver.quit();
```

Running the standalone selenium server using

```
> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
```

Running the script parallelly using `node` command.

I am getting the following error

```
> timers.js:103
>             if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
>                                                                       ^ UnknownError: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with xpath
> '//*[@id="gbqf"]''  caused by Request =>
> {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
> image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"45","Content-Type":"application/json;
> charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:17476"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"xpath\",\"value\":\"//*[@id=\\\"gbqf\\\"]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/440b8b90-0fc8-11e3-8024-5bdaea20ab82/element"}
> Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12
> 15:42:01' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version:
> '2.6.18-8.el5', java.version: '1.6.0_16' Driver info: driver.version:
```

Comment: I do use Ruby binding of selenium.. It is working

Comment: @Babai HTML is same as in [http://google.co.in](http://google.co.in)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance the page has not fully loaded as I know that when I go to google.com, it redirects me to my local google.co.uk site.

Strictly for debugging purposes, put a sleep of 5 seconds before the findElement command.  If that then works, replace with a webdriverWait until the object appears on screen.

However, I have also noticed that you are sending the keys to the "form" element.  Will this work? Do you not want to send keys to the input field?

Comment: I tried this `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000);`. But no use. I also tried taking screenshot. Screenshot is generated properly.

Comment: Yes I am able to get the HTML without any delay.

Comment: Try it with a css selector instead; #gbqf

Comment: I got this `Error Message => 'Unable to find element with css selector '#gbqf''`

Comment: Is the element in the html you printed out?

Comment: Yes HTML is printed out. The code snippet in the question can be exactly run. And the result is same. I tried printing `pageSource` immediately after `driver.get()`, the finding element is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Assert that you are actually on the URL that you expect to be on prior to calling the `findElement` command.

Comment: Or better for single page apps: make a screenshot or dump the page contents.